# Grouping data in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark DataFrame with multiple columns. I would like to group the rows based on one column, and then find the mean of one of there column.

Example:

```
column x | column y
    1    |    2
    1    |    8
    2    |    6
    2    |    4
    3    |    1
    3    |    1
    3    |    1
    3    |    1
```

expect new dataframe:

```
 column x | mean
    1    |    5
    2    |    5
    3    |    1
```

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below snippet would work.

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2),(1,8),(2,6),(2,4),(3,1),(3,1),(3,1),(3,1)], ["col1", "col2"])

>>> df.groupBy("col1").agg({"col2": "avg"}).show()
+----+---------+
|col1|avg(col2)|
+----+---------+
|   1|      5.0|
|   3|      1.0|
|   2|      5.0|
+----+---------+
```

Comment: It was perfect! tks